# Triggers in mysql need correction

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table test1 and test2. test1 has four fields:

```
+——--+——----+-------+------+
| id | name |expanse|amount|
+——--+——----+-------+------+
| 0  | Sid  |  milk |  50  |
| 1  | Josh |   tea |  75  |
+——--+——----+-------+------+
```

I want to write trigger on test1 table; When ever data inserted in test1, its amount and name goes to test2. Test2 have 3 fields: `id`, `name` and `amount`.

Code I'm writing in MySQL SQL query portion of test1 table is

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_test2 ON test1
```

FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN

```
INSERT INTO 
test2
(
    namee,
    amountt

);
SELECT 
    name, 
    amount;
FROM 
    INSERTED 
END//
```

but it's giving error.

Comment: [*CREATE Trigger Syntax*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work on your `CREATE TRIGGER` syntax. As @Ravinder correctly linked in the comments, you can find more details in MySQL manual.

```
CREATE TRIGGER t2test BEFORE INSERT ON test1 FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.name, NEW.amount);
```

This will create basic `INSERT` trigger that will be execute *before* any data is inserted into test1.